# NSOpenGLView subclass not resizing with window

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, nsopenglview

I've been trying to get the NSOpenGLView to resize correctly when resizing the window, but I keep getting weird behaviour which I cannot explain. It looks like so:

Original (What it looks like at the beginning):

[image]

After resize:

[image]

This is my resize code:

```
- (void)reshape
{
    [super reshape];

    CGLLockContext([[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj]);

    NSRect viewRectPoints = [self bounds];

#if SUPPORT_RETINA_RESOLUTION

    NSRect viewRectPixels = [self convertRectToBacking:viewRectPoints];

#else //if !SUPPORT_RETINA_RESOLUTION

    NSRect viewRectPixels = viewRectPoints;

#endif // !SUPPORT_RETINA_RESOLUTION

    [self resizeWithWidth:viewRectPixels.size.width
                  AndHeight:viewRectPixels.size.height];

    CGLUnlockContext([[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj]);
}

- (void) resizeWithWidth:(GLuint)width AndHeight:(GLuint)height
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
}
```

and I'm using: "glViewport(0, 0, m_width, m_height);" whenever I call glDrawArrays();

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you post your drawRect function also?

Answer (score 1):

When resizing the window you should also set the projection matrix to reflect the new dimensions. You didn't post your setup/drawing code, but usually that looks something like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(...); // or glFrustum(), glOrtho(), gluOrtho2D(), ...
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, in these days you might want to consider to leave `NSOpenGLView` behind and move to [`CAOpenGLLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAOpenGLLayer_class/) directly.

I've had too many issues with this silly class to bother any more about `NSOpenGLView` and in layer backed views particularly having a `CAOpenGLLayer` IMHO just gives you more flexibility - and control.
(and less bugs - try getting `NSOpenGLView` to work in a layer backed view hierarchy under 10.9 or pre..).

Plus more functionality right out of the box - or at least under your finger tips (like built-in `CVDisplayLink` support).

Just my 2c.